# Requests start timing out at count of 5

Tags: node.js

I'm looping through a list of long URLs in order to 'unshorten' them -
I'm using [a module](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/node-unshorten) to do this.

My code is below

```
var async = require('async'),
    unshorten = require('unshorten');

var urls = [
    //all these are google
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy',
    'http://t.co/twxHxOtTvy'
]

async.eachSeries(urls, function(shortUrl, callback) {
    unshorten(shortUrl, function(longUrl) {
        console.log(longUrl + ' is where it’s at!');
        callback();
    });
});
```

My issue is, that it reaches 5, and then starts timing out...

If I stop the node app and restart it, it will get up to 5 again, then time out.

I suspect I'm hitting some sort of maximum connection limit, but I don't know where?

For simplicity, the source of `unshorten` is below:

```
(function() {

    var urlLibrary = require('url'),
        http = require('http'),
        https = require('https');

    function unshorten(url, callback) {
        url = urlLibrary.parse(url);
        ('https' == url.protocol ? https : http).request(
            {
                'method': 'HEAD',
                'host': url.host,
                'path': url.pathname
            },
            function(response) {
                if (~[301, 302].indexOf(response.statusCode)) {
                    (callback || console.log)(response.headers.location);
                    return;
                }
            }
        ).end();
    }

    module.exports = unshorten;

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly hitting node.js's default [http agent max socket](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_agent_maxsockets) limit of 5. Read the greant rant @substack wrote in the [hyperquest README](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest) for more details. Also consider other libraries such as [superagent](https://www.npmjs.org/package/superagent) (my personal favorite), hyperquery, request, etc.